# How to set enable disable by default property in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, cordova, android-studio

I am doing some sample app in android development and I am sending the push notification and I have one doubt regarding that.

When we are installing the app, what is the notification status by default. Is it enable or disable.

If it is enable to set disable by default.

Here is the screenshot where notification is ON. Can anybody help me to figure it out where in code to set enable and disable of notification in android.

[image]

In screen 1 am getting only notification icon where as screen 2 notification is floated. 
I want floating notification. Please help.

[image: Screen 1]

[image: Floted]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Notifications are enabled by default and It cannot be disabled programmatically.

Comment: But i want notification on pop up scree, Right now it is  appearing only on notification bar. I am going to setting and then changing it.

Comment: What do you mean by `on pop up screen`? Do you need Heads up notification which appears on the upper part of the screen disturbing user? @David

Comment: when i go to setting and then push notification and then Miscellaneous, there i will get `on pop up screen`. After enabling that i will getting notification as floating.

Comment: Could you please add the screenshots for the same? And also mention which android version and device is it? @David